# Is there way to pass a component scoped service to a modal dialog spawned from that component?

Tags: angular

I have a component that provides a component scoped service. From with the scope of that component a dialog is popped. That resulting dialog does not have access to the injected service in its constructor.

Is there an easy way to have the modal dialog share that service?

Comment: please provide a working stackblitz where the issue happens for debugging, there is no code to fully understand the situation!

Comment: What is the service providing? You might be able to just pass the service-retrieved data to popup from the initialization block, so you might not need to have the service accessed by dialog at all. However, depends on your code, so please share :)